# How to use Async task for audio streaming in android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, http-live-streaming

Can we stream an audio file via async task in android. give me an example if u have done.

Answer (score 10):

Alright I've struggled with this myself for quite a while, since everyone always told me "just use `prepareAsync()` and it will work.

However, you will still need to wait until enough has been buffered before trying to `start()` otherwise you'll get errors and nothing will happen.

First of, let your music-streamer class implement `OnPreparedListener`. This will be used to check if enough has been buffered before starting to play.

Next, use this piece of code to start the buffering and set the listener:

```
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(URL here);
mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
```

You have now set your listener to check whether or not enough has been buffered. Only one more step to go

```
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaplayer) {
    // We now have buffered enough to be able to play
    mediaPlayer.start();
}
```

The song will now be able to start playing without giving errors and all that.

Good luck!

---

As for the fact you want to play the music and be able to stop it at any time, you will need to use a `Service` if you plan on being able to stop your music from all activities. There are a few tutorials about that to be found on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mediaPlayer object.

```
mediaPlayer.setDataSource("Your datasource");
mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
```

The method prepareAsyc: Prepares the player for playback, asynchronously.

For more information see: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

Hope this helps...

Comment: @orioplons ...i did it by using ordinary play,pause and stop button...it works fine, but now i am trying with async task i need music to be played in background and can be stopped any time...

Comment: Probably you will have to override methods of your activity (like on pause, onresume, onstop) to prevent the music stops.